# How to find positive maximum value?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm new to mathematica
I want to find the positive maximum value of a function, but so far I always ended up with either a negative value or the value doesn't even show up.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Z = 500;
W = 100000;
G = 250;
H = 100;
K = 0.5;
T = 30;
L = 4000;
P = 5;
S = 2.5;
Y = 1;
A = 0.1;
V = 2.5;
J = 8000;
f[x_] := 1/
   x {(J*Z*x*(2*Y - x))/(
     2*Y) - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*2*Z*Y*(1 - ((Y - x)/Y)^1.5))/
       3 + (H + T*S + A*L)*((
         2*Z*Y*2*Y - 2*Z*Y*2*Y*((Y - x)/Y)^2.5 - 
          2*Z*Y*5*x*((Y - x)/Y)^1.5)/15))};
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
FindMaximum[f[x], x]
```

Comment: In the definition of `f` you should replace `{` and `}` by normal parentheses `(` and `)`. Then beware that `FindMaximum` makes a local max search, and usually you should only use this with a starting point such as `FindMaximum[f[x],{x,0.2}]` where here `0.2` would be your starting point. There is also `NMaximize` which attempts a global max search.

Comment: The maximum value of a function, if there is a positive one, will be positive automatically simply because a positive value is greater than a negative one. So just find the max and see if it's positive. If you mean you want to find the maximum value of $f(x)$ for $x>0$, please edit the question to state more precisely what you want.

Comment: Tip: [Avoid starting your variable/function names with a capital, especially single capitals.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)

Answer (score 3):

Since `f[x]` is complex value, we use `Re@f[x]` to restrict on reals.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] = 1/
    x ((J*Z*x*(2*Y - x))/(2*
        Y) - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*2*Z*Y*(1 - ((Y - x)/Y)^1.5))/
        3 + (H + T*S + 
          A*L)*((2*Z*Y*2*Y - 2*Z*Y*2*Y*((Y - x)/Y)^2.5 - 
            2*Z*Y*5*x*((Y - x)/Y)^1.5)/15)));
Plot[Re@f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
FindMaximum[{Re@f[x], x > 0}, x]
```

> `{1.09904*10^6, {x -> 0.263896}}`

Comment: Or `f[x_]:=Rationalize[ 1/
    x ((J*Z*x*(2*Y - x))/(2*
        Y) - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*2*Z*Y*(1 - ((Y - x)/Y)^1.5))/
        3 + (H + T*S + 
          A*L)*((2*Z*Y*2*Y - 2*Z*Y*2*Y*((Y - x)/Y)^2.5 - 
            2*Z*Y*5*x*((Y - x)/Y)^1.5)/15))),0]`

Comment: When i tried it in my mathematica why the result is like this -->During evaluation of In[791]:= FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value {-432503.} is not a real number at {x} = {0.999994}.

During evaluation of In[791]:= FindMaximum::grad: Evaluation of the gradient of function Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[-{Re[(-107500+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<2>>])/x]}],Block},{0,{{{},1,0,Hold[x],0,0}}},<<3>>,{None,None,None}] failed at {1.}.

Out[807]= FindMaximum[{Re[f[x]], x > 0}, x]

Comment: @ShafaKeysaRinjaniHananta  Please `Clear[f]`.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you so much! It's working now

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Z = 500;
W = 100000;
G = 250;
H = 100;
K = 0.5;
T = 30;
L = 4000;
P = 5;
S = 2.5;
Y = 1;
A = 0.1;
V = 2.5;
J = 8000;
```

Do not use list brackets in place of parentheses. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

```
f[x_] := 1/
    x ((J*Z*x*(2*Y - x))/(2*
        Y) - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*2*Z*Y*(1 - ((Y - x)/Y)^1.5))/
        3 + (H + T*S + 
          A*L)*((2*Z*Y*2*Y - 2*Z*Y*2*Y*((Y - x)/Y)^2.5 - 
            2*Z*Y*5*x*((Y - x)/Y)^1.5)/15)));
```

The function is real when

```
FunctionDomain[f[x], x]

(* x < 0 || 0 < x <= 1 *)
```

Use the domain of interest as a constraint

```
{max, arg} = Maximize[{f[x], 0 < x <= 1}, x]

(* {1.09904*10^6, {x -> 0.263896}} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. arg]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is as follows.

```
f[x_] := 1/x ((J*Z*x*(2*Y - x))/(2*
     Y) - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*2*Z*Y*(1 - ((Y - x)/Y)^1.5))/
     3 + (H + T*S +  A*L)*((2*Z*Y*2*Y - 2*Z*Y*2*Y*((Y - x)/Y)^2.5 - 
     2*Z*Y*5*x*((Y - x)/Y)^1.5)/15)));
NMaximize[{f[x], x > 0 && x < 1}, x]
```

> `{1.09904*10^6, {x -> 0.263896}}`